# plotting time series by column with identifier

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a 3 separate datasets in a time series with columns from 9am to 4pm, and they are identified by days until an event. I am trying to plot each row (percentages) from 9am to 4pm by `days_from_event` on a set of subplots, but cannot seem to be able to generate the plot I'm looking for.

I tried to jimmy-rig it and drop columns I wasn't trying to plot

```
df_mean_test = df_mean_test.drop(['days_from_event', 'id', 'index'], axis = 1)
df_mean_test = df_mean_test.transpose()
df_mean_test.head(15)
```

which yields:

[image: Image of dataframe]

From there I created a `Time` column with index values of `9am, 10am, 11am, etc.` then I tried to plot with:

```
df_mean_test.plot(x = df_mean_test.index, y = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6'], 
kind = 'line', subplots = True, layout = (1,7), 
xlabel = 'session hours', ylabel = 'percent change')
```

but received this traceback error.

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-204-f03b7d25ab5b> in <module>
----> 1 df_mean_test.plot(x = df_mean_test.index, y = 
['0','1','2','3','4','5','6'], kind = 'line', subplots = True, layout = (1,7) 
xlabel = 'session hours', ylabel = 'percent change')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in __call__(self, *args, 
**kwargs)
    810                 if is_integer(x) and not data.columns.holds_integer():
    811                     x = data_cols[x]
--> 812                 elif not isinstance(data[x], ABCSeries):
    813                     raise ValueError("x must be a label or position")
    814                 data = data.set_index(x)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2804             if is_iterator(key):
   2805                 key = list(key)
-> 2806             indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1, 
raise_missing=True)[1]
   2807 
   2808         # take() does not accept boolean indexers

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in 
_get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis, raise_missing)
   1550             keyarr, indexer, new_indexer = ax._reindex_non_unique(keyarr)
   1551 
-> 1552         self._validate_read_indexer(
   1553             keyarr, indexer, o._get_axis_number(axis), 
raise_missing=raise_missing
   1554         )

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in 
_validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis, raise_missing)
   1638             if missing == len(indexer):
   1639                 axis_name = self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)
-> 1640                 raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
   1641 
   1642             # We (temporarily) allow for some missing keys with .loc, 
except in

KeyError: "None of [Index(['9am', '10am', '11am', '12pm', '1pm', '2pm', '3pm', 
'4pm'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

How would I go about either fixing this error, or properly plotting what I'm looking to do? Thank you so much for the assistance!

Here is a sample image of the style of plot I'm trying to recreate:
[image]

Here is the dataframe for attempts copied with `df.to_clipboard`:

```
,9am,10am,11am,12pm,1pm,2pm,3pm,4pm,days_from_event
0,0.0,0.165,-0.082,0.355,1.117,1.09,0.672,0.621,-3
1,0.0,-0.402,-0.831,-0.916,-0.61,-0.637,-1.309,-1.91,-2
2,0.0,0.235,0.555,1.0,0.976,0.862,0.796,0.725,-1
3,0.0,0.308,0.593,0.417,0.712,0.74,0.286,-0.089,0
4,0.0,0.172,0.154,0.223,-0.029,-0.499,0.077,0.914,1
5,0.0,-0.38,-0.321,0.014,0.012,0.598,0.849,1.077,2
6,0.0,-0.267,-0.055,0.023,0.512,0.505,0.144,-0.352,3
```

Comment: If you are plotting the index as the x-axis (e.g. `df_mean_test.plot(x = df_mean_test.index,...)`), it is not necessary to specify `x`. And if you're plotting all of the columns, then don't specify `y`. Use `df_mean_test.plot(subplots=True, layout=(1,7), xlabel='session hours', ylabel='percent change')`. Follow `pep8`, don't put spaces around the parameter `=` (e.g. `kind = 'line'` should be `kind='line'`).

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for; thank you! @TrentonMcKinney